# Create Custom Fields in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to push data (through rest api) which has custom fields and values into salesforce. How do I create custom field using rest or soap api in salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

For creation object fields in Salesforce via API you need to use [Metadata Api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm).

See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) related to interaction with fields for more information.

Comment: thanks for your response. Does metadata api calls can be made only by adding their external jar and accessing the methods they provide. Is it possible to send the xml body as post to a url (like in REST Api) for creating fields?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use REST for your needs, currently Salesforce provide Metadata API only via SOAP. You can find more info follow this link  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20763/creating-a-custom-object-using-rest-api

Comment: Dude, that thread was like 3 years back and yeah i came across this one before posting this question here. Have no idea why it's been put on hold for these many days (years)